# Maintaining transparency of layer during edit sessions of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, transparency-opacity

I'm editing the polygons of one shapefile to more closely match the polygons of another shapefile, essentially tracing the one over the other. I've set the transparency of the layer under edit to 75%, which allows me to more easily recognize errors and discrepancies compared to the other, more accurate shapefile. The problem is that while I have a polygon selected during an edit session, it changes the transparency to something closer to 20%, which makes the process much more difficult. Is there a way to lock transparency during selection/edit sessions?

Comment: What version of the software are you using?

Comment: Why not just choose no fill color?

Comment: @ian you should submit that as an answer, that's how I work around this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works in 10.2.1 and essentially turns the sketch hollow as suggested by Ian. As soon as you stop being in sketch mode it returns to your selected transparency.

In the Editor toolbar go to Editor > Options and untick *Use symbolized feature during editing*.